# What is the maximum size of an environment integer variable value in Postman?

Tags: postman

I am trying to set below value to environment variable:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("MessageID", 1152921509044942942);
```

But after that its showing below value:

```
1152921509044942800
```

Comment: Does the environment have to be an integer value?

Comment: No, its not required as integer?

Comment: then, why not set it as a string value? Or is the goal of your question only to find the maximum size of a numeric value?

Comment: actually this value I will get in the  API response body, and API will return in integer only.

Comment: Your problem is rather the `JSON.parse(responseBody)`, you could be better of with `BigInt(responseBody)`

Comment: @lcepickle  Even not working with BigInt - postman.setEnvironmentVariable("MessageID", BigInt(jsonData.Messages[0].To[0].MessageID)); Original value in response is 576460756880814126, but variable is showing 576460756880814080